# NuGet repository in TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment, jetbrains-ide, octopus-deploy

Okay guys so I'm going a little nuts here.

I am currently testing settings with TeamCity and Octopus deploy and I am running into an issue where The most recent Nuget Package is being deployed instead of the one I am specifying.

So for example... I once deployed a NuGet Package called "TeamCityTest 72.0.0".

I now want to deploy a package called "TeamCityTest 1.0.0.0".

Since 72.0.0 is the highest value, Octopus just reuses that package from my TeamCity feed and ignores my release that I was attempting.

I am trying to find out how to manage the TeamCity nuget repository but there doesn't seem to be much documentation on how to do this. Essentially, I would like to see what is in my nuget repository, clear it, remove it, whatever I need to do. Is there some secret UI that I am not aware of? How can I manage my TeamCity nuget repository?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options. The first I think is the correct one for your particular scenario.

If you edit the settings for the build configuration in Team City and set the "Clean Artifacts" policy to 1 day, it will delete out the builds and packages associated with them. (You need appropriate permissions to do this, i.e. System Admin). This is essentially the "etch-a-sketch end of the world" as it will delete a lot of stuff!

The second options is more precise. You can issue a HTTP DELETE against the REST API for a specific build:

```
http://<server>:<port>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/<build ID>
```

You could use a REST plugin in your browser, or write a little app to call the API. You'll need to provide basic authorization.

Comment: You can also remove a build via the UI - open the build summary and click Actions -> Remove...